# Is therer such a thing as the height of a node in a BST?

Tags: binary-search-tree

I'm getting confused the more I search. Does the term "height" only apply to the root node of a BST? Or does each node have its own corresponding height? Similarly, does each node of a BST have a corresponding level?

Comment: This is all explained on [Wikipedia - Tree - Terminology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(data_structure)#Terminology)

Answer (score 0):

Height of a BST or any binary tree is the total number of edges from the root node to the most distant leaf node. You are probably getting confused with recursion when a node on another level is passed as the root. For every node, it is the parent of its subtree, so it is the root for that subtree. That's how recursion works.